# Why when web scraping does the valueError: Not enough values to unpack in BeautifulSoup happen and what does it mean

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

So I am scraping a [website][1] and I want to
Retrieve the webpages based on these URLs and convert each into a beautifulsoup object

Retrieve Car Manufacturing Year, Engine, Price, Dealer information (if it is available), and the URL (href) to access the detailed car information.

When I run the code I get the error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)" when I remove one value instead of having make, model, year, and price I change it to make, model, and price and it comes up with another error "too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://jammer.ie/used-cars?page={}&per-page=12"

all_data = []

for page in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).text, "html.parser")

    for car in soup.select(".car"):
        info = car.select_one(".top-info").get_text(strip=True, separator="|")
        make, model, year, price = info.split("|")
        dealer_name = car.select_one(".dealer-name h6").get_text(
            strip=True, separator=" "
        )
        address = car.select_one(".address").get_text(strip=True)

        features = {}
        for feature in car.select(".car--features li"):
            k = feature.img["src"].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
            v = feature.span.text
            features[f"feature_{k}"] = v

        all_data.append(
            {
                "make": make,
                "model": model,
                "year": year,
                "price": price,
                "dealer_name": dealer_name,
                "address": address,
                "url": "https://jammer.ie"
                + car.select_one("a[href*=vehicle]")["href"],
                **features,
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
# prints sample data to screen:
print(df.tail().to_markdown(index=False))
# saves all data to CSV
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a check if the car contains model or not:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://jammer.ie/used-cars?page={}&per-page=12"

all_data = []

for page in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).text, "html.parser")

    for car in soup.select(".car"):
        info = car.select_one(".top-info").get_text(strip=True, separator="|")
        info = info.split("|")
        if len(info) == 4:
            make, model, year, price = info
        else:
            make, year, price = info
            model = "N/A"
        dealer_name = car.select_one(".dealer-name h6").get_text(
            strip=True, separator=" "
        )
        address = car.select_one(".address").get_text(strip=True)

        features = {}
        for feature in car.select(".car--features li"):
            k = feature.img["src"].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
            v = feature.span.text
            features[f"feature_{k}"] = v

        all_data.append(
            {
                "make": make,
                "model": model,
                "year": year,
                "price": price,
                "dealer_name": dealer_name,
                "address": address,
                "url": "https://jammer.ie"
                + car.select_one("a[href*=vehicle]")["href"],
                **features,
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
# prints sample data to screen:
print(df.tail().to_markdown(index=False))
# saves all data to CSV
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

| make | model | year | price | dealer_name | address | url | feature_speed | feature_engine | feature_transmission | feature_door-icon1 | feature_petrol5 | feature_hatchback | feature_owner | feature_paint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SEAT | Leon | 2015 | Price on application | McNamara Motors | Co. Cork | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/166591-seat-leon-2015 | 45000 miles | 1.2 litres | Manual | 5 doors | Petrol | Hatchback | 2 previous owners | Grey |
| Toyota | Verso | 2012 | €8,250 | Amcc | Co. Dublin | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/166590-toyota-verso-2012 | 98179 miles | 1.5 litres | Automatic | 4 doors | Petrol | MPV | nan | Purple |
| Mazda | Demio | 2012 | €7,950 | Amcc | Co. Dublin | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/166589-mazda-demio-2012 | 82644 miles | 1.3 litres | Automatic | 4 doors | Petrol | Hatchback | nan | Red |
| Toyota | Corolla | 2017 | €14,950 | Amcc | Co. Dublin | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/166588-toyota-corolla-2017 | 78916 miles | 1.5 litres | Automatic | 4 doors | nan | Estate | nan | Silver |
| Mazda | Demio | 2013 | €8,950 | Amcc | Co. Dublin | https://jammer.ie/vehicle/166587-mazda-demio-2013 | 53439 miles | 1.3 litres | Automatic | 4 doors | Petrol | Hatchback | nan | Grey |